# irrational root of a number number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $x>0$, and let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. Can we make sense of $x^{\alpha}$ ? What about the case $x<0$ ?

Comment: You have tagged this as [tag:complex-numbers]. Is that intentional? Because involving complex numbers will drastically change any answer.

Comment: @Arthur, it won't matter because by stating $x > 0$ and $\alpha$ irrational the author has implicity made them real.

Comment: @ApoorvKhurasia But for complex numbers (even though they happen to lie on the real line), exponentiation is multivalued. So it does matter.

Comment: @Arthur I see. You mean $x^\alpha$ being complex. Fair enough and valid point.

Comment: @ Arthur. I am looking for any sense of $x^{\alpha}$, so it is wise to start looking in the larger set.

Comment: @Medo Actually, no, with these things it's usually wise to start in the more restricted set, learn what properties the concept has there, then try to generalize and see what you have to give up on in the process. For instance, when you generalize from natural to integer exponents, you lose the ability to raise $0$ to powers. When you generalize to rational exponents, you lose the ability to raise complex and negative numbers to powers (at least in a nice, unique, well-defined way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everything here is real, there are several ways to make sense of $x^\alpha$.

The one most people learn in school is (possibly a simplification of) the following: Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $\alpha$. Then we define
$$
x^\alpha = \lim_{n\to\infty}x^{a_n}
$$
One should, of course, make sure that *any* sequence converging to $\alpha$ gives the same limit.

The one I think is most often used as a definition by mathematicians is simply
$$
x^\alpha = \exp(\alpha\cdot\ln x)
$$
where both $\exp$ and $\ln$ may be defined several different ways, for instance
$$
\exp(a) = 1 + a + \frac{a^2}2 + \frac{a^3}6 + \cdots + \frac{a^n}{n!} + \cdots\\
\ln x = \int_1^x\frac1tdt
$$
There are many definitions to choose from here, though.

Then we have this one, which is not so common, but somewhat of a favourite of mine, if one knows a little group theory: Consider $(\Bbb R, +)$, the real numbers with the operation of addition and $(\Bbb R^+, \cdot)$, the positive real numbers with multiplication. As groups, these are isomorphic, and there are many different homomorphisms between them, but each one may be uniquely determined by where it sends $1\in (\Bbb R, +)$ (and we probably need to assume that it's "nice" for some suitable notion of niceness, like being continuous, or monotonic).

One of these homomorphisms $f: (\Bbb R, +)\to (\Bbb R^+, \cdot)$ has $f(1) = x$. We then define
$$
x^\alpha = f(\alpha)
$$

Comment: Of these, the middle one is probably the one most easily generalized to complex numbers. $\exp$ is not problematic at all, but $\ln$ will give some troubles that need to be handled in some way.

Comment: What if $x<0$ ?

Comment: @Medo You're right. Negative base raised to a non-integer exponent necessarily puts you into complex numbers. Again, the second definition is probably the best one to use to try to sort out the kinks. You have to decide what you want the logarithm of $x$ to be (the two most popular choices are $\ln(-x) \pm \pi i$), and then go for it.

Comment: You are saying that if $x<0$ then we can still write $x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha(\ln{(-x)}+\pi \dot{\imath})}$ ?

Comment: @Medo That is one popular way to make sense of $x^\alpha$ in that case, yes.